# Any bash investigation script for kubernetes / ingress-nginx - getting 503?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress, azure-aks

I just broke my cluster kubernetes/ingress-nginx and I get 503 regardless of what I am trying. Does anyone know of a bash investigation script that could help with kubernetes/ingress-nginx or the cluster? I am running on AKS. I did look at krew but I cannot risk to install it on these clusters.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Start by looking at the logs of your nginx controller. 
“Kubectl logs <nginx> -n <namespace>”

Comment: Also, [krew](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/krew#readme) is a `kubectl` plugin manager, and does not install anything on your cluster. If using a plugin manager worries you, then you are welcome to just download the plugin and place it on your PATH, since that's how kubectl discovers plugins

Comment: Am I missing anything, after I installed krew, the "kubectl krew" does not work, but "kubectl-krew" command works for some command?

Comment: Besides looking for specific tools that do that you might also provide some minimal reproducible example like you deployments, ingress config etc.